# Why isn't my PythonScript for Notepad++ running?

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm running NPP 6.3.1 (UNICODE) and the current pythonscript plugin (python 2.7.6, pythonscript 0.9.2.0)

I recently got a new machine and had to reinstall both NPP and PythonScript (PS).  I wrote a basic script a little while ago and had been using it a good bit and it worked fine using the PS plugin.

I installed everything and run the script through the PS plugin menu but nothing happens.  I try it again and now, I keep getting the following error:

> Another script is currently running.  Running two scripts at the same time could produce unpredictable results, and therefore is disabled.

The script is designed to search the document and find the next available point number and insert it at the cursor.  Like I said, it's a simple script that has a defined start and end.  I've never had a problem with it before.  So, I decided to create a new script (test.py) which consists entirely of the following:

```
console.write("test")
```

Nothing.  The console doesn't show any activity no matter what I do, which leads me to believe that the script isn't even starting, even though it says that it loads up (in 16ms) and says its ready...

I tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling but still nothing.  I haven't tried previous versions yet.

Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: Write messages to file (similar to log file) - to see whether program is working and what it is doing.

Comment: Are you sure the current pythonscript plugin is compatible with the latest NPP 6.3.1? PyNPP is dated 2012-02-26, whereas NPP 6.3 was released on 2013-02-03.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not have the most current version.  After installing version 6.6.6 and PythonScript 1.0.2, it works.

Just want to leave this information for the next people who come in with this problem.

Comment: It's not working for me. I am using PythonScript 1.5.4.0 and Notepad++ 7.9.5